# How to set row height in Grid?

Tags: grid-layouts

I always thought that `Grid` (and the underlying `GridBox`) and the general handling of tabular objects is a bit weird in *Mathematica*. One particularly annoying fact is that while one can set column widths explictly, the same cannot be done to row heights, because each row is set to the height of its largest content by default. I don't really understand this asymmetry between the two dimensions. Does anyone have any insight on this matter?

As a more specific question: How to set the row height to be exactly 1, by clipping the content if necessary (i.e. some part of it should not be visible)?

```
Grid[{
  {"000000000\n111111111\n222222222", "000000000"},
  {"000000000", "000000000"}
  },
 ItemSize -> {{10, 5}, {1, 1}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can this be done with only `Grid` or do I have to map a `Pane` with explicit height value to each element (converting from pixels to [em](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography))s, as `Pane` uses the latter)?

Comment: In fact, the behavior of `ItemSize` is [explained](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ItemSize.html) (the third example of **Scope** section: it sets *minimal* height, not fixed height) but I agree that it is not entirely consistent or desirable behavior (I do not know the rationale behind this design...).

Comment: @Yu-SungChang Could we imagine this behaviour being "corrected" in the future? I have the filling that there's a lot of historic "garbage" accumulated in all these definitions, and this, mixed up with some bugs, makes a lot of confusion and frustration. For instance, I find the following behaviour extremely confusing: `Grid[{{Item[Rotate["this is a long test example", Pi/2],ItemSize -> {3, 50}]}}, Frame -> True]`. I know that you probably can't answer to this comment, but I would like to express my frustration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Pane` construct is quite flexible. I cannot imagine not using it with table for fluid sizes control and features. Here are your data:

```
data={{"000000000\n111111111\n222222222","000000000"},{"000000000","000000000"}}
```

This will fix the cell size and **cut off the content** if it won't fit:

```
Grid[Map[Pane[#, ImageSize -> {80, 30}] &, data, {2}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

This will fix the cell size and **shrink the content** if it won't fit

```
Grid[Map[Pane[#, ImageSize -> {80, 30}, ImageSizeAction -> 
"ShrinkToFit"] &, data, {2}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Use **Scrollbars** to view the content that did not fit

```
data2 = 200! {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
Grid[Map[Pane[#, ImageSize -> {200, 100}, Scrollbars -> 
{False, True}] &, data2, {2}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**Forbid line-breaks** to use horizontal scrolling only for small row height (updated after @Yu-Sung comment):

```
data2 = 200! {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
Grid[Map[Pane[#, ImageSize -> {150, 30}, Scrollbars -> {True, False}] &, 
data2, {2}], Frame -> All, BaseStyle -> {LineBreakWithin -> False}]
```

[image]

Comment: `LineBreakWithin` can be set as `BaseStye` option value of `Grid`, instead of individually using `Style`: `Grid[blah..., BaseStyle -> {LineBreakWithin -> False}]`

Comment: @Yu-SungChang Nice catch ;-) , thanks, updated!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of just `Grid` you might try putting together `Row` and `Column` expressions. And then control the height as well as width using `ItemSize` option in the columns.