# How can I set several Grids to have the same size?

Tags: grid-layouts

I generate different `Grids` with different columns. Automatically `ImageSizes` are fixed depending upon the data. So every `Grid` has a different size.

```
grid1=Grid[{{Item["Name", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, Alignment -> Left], 
             Item["Branch", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue,Alignment -> Left], 
             Item["Section", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue,Alignment -> Left]},
            {"s", "IT", "A"}, 
            {"u", "IT", "A"}, 
            {"b","IT", "A"}, 
            {"b", "IT", "A"},
            {"b", "IT", "A"}}, Frame -> True
         ];

 grid2=Grid[{{Item["Name", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, Alignment -> Left], 
             Item["Branch", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue,Alignment -> Left], 
             Item["Section", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue,Alignment -> Left]},
            {"subrahmanyam", "IT", "A"}, 
            {"Madhu", "IT", "A"}, 
            {"Kiran","IT", "A"}, 
            {"KalyanKumar", "IT", "A"},
            {"Pavan", "IT", "A"}}, Frame -> True
         ];
  grid3 = Grid[{{"Main", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, 
 SpanFromLeft}, {Item["Name", Frame -> True, 
  Background -> LightBlue, Alignment -> Left], 
 Item["Branch", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, 
  Alignment -> Left], 
 Item["Section", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, 
  Alignment -> Left], 
 Item["Section", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, 
  Alignment -> Left]}, {"subrahmanyam", "IT", "A", "g"}, {"Madhu",
  "IT", "A"}, {"Kiran", "IT", "A"}, {"KalyanKumar", "IT", 
 "A"}, {"Pavan", "IT", "A"}}, Frame -> True, 
  ItemSize -> {{10, 7, 7, 7}, 1}];

 finalGrid=Grid[{{grid3},{grid1}, {grid2}, {grid1}, {grid2}, {grid1}, {grid2}}]
```

grid1Image=

[image]

grid2Image=

[image]

grid3Image=

[image]

finalImage=

[image]

If I place all the `Grids` columnwise within `Grid`, it doesn't look good.

So, I want to fix all the `Grids` with the same sizes. I tried various things, but nothing seems to work.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 7):

**Update 3:** Dealing with subgrids with different number of columns:

The main difficulty with differing number of columns is that both `Spacings` and `ItemSizes` in the subgrids have to be taken into account to get the same **total width** for all the subgrids. With $m$ subgrids indexed $i=1, ..., m$, where subgrid $g_i$ has $n_i$ columns with column widths

$w_{i j}, \left(j = 1, ..., n_i \right) $

and spacings

$s_{i j}, \left(j = 1, ..., n_i +1 \right) $,

total width $\tau_i$ of subgrid $i$ is

$ \tau_i =\sum _{j=1}^{n_i}  \left(s_{i  j} + w_{i  j} \right) + s_{i \left(n_i +1 \right)}   $

In the following I added the following option settings to the three subgrids:

```
  (* grids 1 and 2 :*)
  Spacings -> 4, ItemSize -> {{15, {6}}, 1} 
  (* grid3 *)
  Spacings -> 3, ItemSize -> {{15, {4}}, 1}
```

With these settings:

```
 Grid[{{grid3}, {grid2}, {grid1}, {grid2}, {grid1}, {grid2}}]
```

gives

[image]

Note: using the following settings

```
 Spacings -> 4, ItemSize -> {{Scaled[6/24], {Scaled[3/24]}}, 1} (* grids 1 and 2*)
 Spacings -> 3, ItemSize -> {{Scaled[6/24], {Scaled[2/24]}}, 1}  (* grid 3 *)
```

produces the same result.

---

**Original post:** Subgrids with the same number of columns

You need to set common values for the column widths using `ItemSize` in the two grids.

```
 grid1 = Grid[{{Item["Name", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue,
     Alignment -> Left], 
    Item["Branch", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, Alignment -> Left], 
    Item["Section", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue,  Alignment -> Left]},
     {"s", "IT", "A"}, {"u", "IT", "A"}, 
     {"b", "IT", "A"}, {"b", "IT", "A"}, {"b", "IT", "A"}}, Frame -> True, 
   ItemSize -> {{10, 7, 7}, 1}]; 
  grid2 = Grid[{{Item["Name", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue, 
    Alignment -> Left], 
   Item["Branch", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue,  Alignment -> Left], 
   Item["Section", Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue,  Alignment -> Left]}, 
   {"subrahmanyam", "IT", "A"}, {"Madhu", "IT",  "A"}, 
   {"Kiran", "IT", "A"}, {"KalyanKumar", "IT", "A"}, 
   {"Pavan",  "IT", "A"}}, Frame -> True, 
   ItemSize -> {{10, 7, 7}, 1}]; 
  finalGrid = Grid[{{grid1}, {grid2}, {grid1}, {grid2}, {grid1}, {grid2}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use

```
   ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.1], Scaled[.05], Scaled[.05]}, 1}
```

Note: If the length of the list `colwidths` in `ItemSize->{colwidths, rowheights}` is less than the number of columns in the grid, the remaining column widths will be determined by the default settings. If you put an extra layer of `{}` around `colwidths`, (that is,`ItemSize->{{colwidths}, rowheights}`) the column widths will be determined by cycling through the numbers provided in the list `colwidths`.

**Update: Finer details of `Grid` option settings:**

From [Docs >> Grid >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html)

> [image]

Illustration with a simple example adapted from the documentation examples:

```
data = {{"first", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},  {"second", 11, 5, 6, 4, 2},
  {"third", 111, 8, 9, 3, 3},   {"fourth", 1111, 10, 11, 2, 2}}; 

 Grid[Prepend[data, {"name", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}],
  Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], 
   {White, Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}},
 Dividers -> All,  Alignment -> {{Left, Right, {Left}}},
 ItemSize -> {{{7, 3, 5}}, 1}]
```

[image]

```
 Grid[Prepend[data, {"name", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}], Dividers -> All,
 Background -> {None, {Lighter[Yellow, .9], {White, 
     Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], .8]}}},
 Alignment -> {{Left, Right, {Left}}},
 ItemSize -> {{10, 5, {2}}, 1}]
```

[image]

**Further reading:**

From *Mathematica* documentation pages:

[Grid](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html)
[ItemSize](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ItemSize.html)
[Tutorial- Grids Rows and Columns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GridsRowsAndColumnsOverview.html)

Related Q/As on *Mathematica.SE*:

[Setting equal column widths in Grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8636/125)
[Setting row heights in Grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3545/125)

Comment: ,if `Grid` have only 3 columns,it is working fine.If `Grid` have more number of 3 columns,it is not working.How can I solve that?

Comment: sorry still it was not working..

Comment: @subbu, you can change `{10,7,7}` to match the number of columns you have, setting the width of each column. If the list you provide for column widths is shorter than the number of columns, widhts of remaining columns are determined by the default settings. By putting column width numbers in another layer of braces, you can cycle through these numbers to set the all the column widths. That is, if you have six columns, say, setting ItemSize->{{{10,5}}, 1} is equivalent to setting `ItemSize->{{10,5,10,5,10,5}, 1}`.

Comment: ... Or, if you use `ItemSize->{{10,5,{2}}, 1}`, then the first column will have width `10`, second `5` and third and remaining columns will have width `2`. Please see my edits to the post.

Comment: @subbu, sorry I was missing a set of braces in my earlier comment. If it is still not working, could you please post an example of your input and what you are getting?

Comment: I understood your code and it works fine too.But your code was not suitable to my question, because, in my case I have 2 `Grids` with 3 columns and 4 columns,and `ItemSize->{{10}, 1}`.The first `grid` has 3 columns meaning ,that the size is 30.Similarly, the second `grid` has 4 columns, meaning,that size is 40. Both `grid`sizes are not equal so both `grids` do not appear with the same size.Reason why I think your `ItemSize->{{10}, 1}` notation is not suitable for me.

Comment: @subbu, I see - this is quite different. I suggest that you update your question with this new information  because it is a critical part of your requirements. In the example in your original post, the cause of different grid sizes is not the number of columns, but the differences in the content sizes in the two grids and using the same column widths fixes that problem. I will update my post with suggestions.

Comment: ... thanks -- I see that you updated the question

Comment: ,sorry I didn't understand your formula` i = sum of ni+1 spacings + sum of ni column widths`...If you don't mine can you explain clearly

Comment: @subbu, it is "total width of subgrid _i_ = ..." . (where subgrid _i_ has $n_i$ columns).